# Determining connectivity of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, graph-connectivity

I recently came across the Havel-Hakimi Theorem/Algorithm which tells us whether a simple graph with a given degree sequence can exist. This however does not tell us whether the graph is connected or not.

Is there any such procedure that can tell us about the above criterion which does not require drawing the graph itself, i.e. by using its degree sequence?

Comment: You can do a simple DFS from some node to determine all the vertices reachable from said node. This will tell you whether the graph is connected.

Also, the Havel-Hakimi algorithm is used to determine if a given sequence is graphic, i.e. the degree sequence of a simple graph. If you merely want to know whether a graph is simple, it suffices to check that there are no multiedges/self-loops.

Comment: For connectedness of a graph you could read Wikipedia article [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Comment: @MishaLavrov, It seems I had worded my question slightly inaccurately. It is corrected now.

Comment: Do you want to know if there is *any* connected graph with this degree sequence, or if *all* graphs with this degree sequence are connected?

Comment: The former condition (any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a given sequence $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$ to be the degree sequence of a connected graph, we need three things:

1. It's graphic: that is, it's the degree sequence of some (simple) graph. This can be checked with the Havel-Hakimi algorithm.
2. $d_1 + d_2 + \dots + d_n \ge 2(n-1)$; this tells us that there are at least $n-1$ edges, the minimum needed for the graph to be connected.
3. $\min\{d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n\} \ge 1$; this tells us that there are no isolated vertices.

These three conditions are also clearly necessary, and turn out to also be sufficient.

To prove that, we start with any graph that has this degree sequence. If it's not connected, we will reduce the number of connected components until it is.

If a graph with at least $n-1$ edges has no cycles, then it must be connected (and a tree). So if our graph is not connected, it has a cycle. Let $vw$ be any edge of the cycle; let $xy$ be any edge that's not in the same component as the cycle. (The other components can't be isolated vertices, by condition 3, so they must contain at least one edge.)

Delete edges $vw$ and $xy$, and replace them by edges $vx$ and $wy$. (These edges weren't there before, because their endpoints were in different connected components.) This operation doesn't change any degrees; however, it reduces the number of connected components by $1$. Before, $v,w$ were in one connected component and $x,y$ were in another. Now, $v$ and $w$ are still connected (since $vw$ part of a cycle); $x$ and $y$ are part of that component now, and so was everything connected to $x$ or to $y$.

If we keep doing this, eventually, we'll end up with a connected graph.